# Login With Salesforce into my web app | REACT JS

Tags: reactjs, authentication, salesforce

Hy, I didn't know about it too much, but working on the functionality to log in with Salesforce account into my app.

I'm Following these steps

Hy, I didn't know about it too much, but working on the same functionality.

Step 01: I hit this URL First

[https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize?client_id=${clientId}&redirect_uri=${redirectUri}&response_type=code](https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize?client_id=$%7BclientId%7D&redirect_uri=$%7BredirectUri%7D&response_type=code)

STEP 02: Get an Access token from Salesforce by using the code provided by Salesforce.

For this, I'm hitting the POST API

[https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token?client_id=${clientId}&client_secret=${ClientSecret}&redirect_uri=${redirectUri}&grant_type=authorization_code](https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token?client_id=$%7BclientId%7D&client_secret=$%7BClientSecret%7D&redirect_uri=$%7BredirectUri%7D&grant_type=authorization_code)

That's it, I just complete this and am stuck here, the access token API giving me an error

[image]

[image]